# after installing symfony, i cannot load /web/app.php , internal server error

Tags: php, apache, symfony, installation, internal-server-error

I have downloaded and installed symfony. I have a dir 'path' in my htdocs file. For some reason i cannot load in localhost the path/web/app.php or other files in the web directory. When i browse the path/ dir, I get:
Index of /path

- Parent Directory
- .gitignore
- .idea/
- LICENSE README.md
- UPGRADE-2.2.md
- UPGRADE-2.3.md
- UPGRADE-2.4.md
- UPGRADE.md bin/
- composer.json
- composer.lock
- vendor/

but no /web/ or no /app/ directory. When I browse toward path/web/ , the I get Internal Server Error. In the log, I have: "DirectoryIndex not allowed here"
When I browse toward path/web/app.php , the I get Internal Server Error. In the log, I have: "order not allowed here"

In my windows explorer, I can get in the path/web/ directory and access the file, but I cannot load them on localhost.

There is nothing in the "permissions" that seems wrong. I did it also as an administrator, but same problem. I have checked httpd.conf of apache, changed some "deny from all" to "allow from all" but didnt help neither.

Comment: Did you install symfony per [their guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html) or did you unzip a folder into that directory?

Comment: How did you install Symfony2? Did you used composer.phar in order to install Symfony2?

Comment: This does not look like a full symfony installation, you are missing some folders, try to re-install or follow the guide linked above